# ASP.NET web api SPA project layout

Tags: backbone.js, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, requirejs

I am building a proof-of-concept line-of-business Single Page App. I want to use ASP.NET web api for the REST service layer, and Backbone.js and Require.js on client. I would like to use modular structuring of js files and templates (Require.js) so the source code of the app would not end up in one html page.

I havent found an example how to lay out the project in Visual Studio, and what project type should I choose. Should Web Api be in one project, and web application in another, or should it be mixed. Any advice or best practice would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did previously for the same goals was to put the WebApi and Web application in the same project. It makes thigs easier from the point of view that you will everything set up when you create the project in Visual Studio.

There is a slight problem in having the webapi in a different project: since you have to put that on a separate hosting or eventually on the same hosting but bound on a different port or virtual directory, it may need some time setting up IIS... eventually in the past we used the Url rewrite module to redirect calls from the Web App to the Web Api application. There may be simpler settings but again it will require a bit of time, depending on your confidence in setting up IIS...

For starter/proof of concept probably having everything on the same application will make things smoother. You may want to keep Domain Models and DB access in separate projects so if eventually you end up splitting the WebApi from the Web App you can still reference those two without problems.

In the end, the Web Application will only have one controller with one action (`Home/Index` maybe) and this will be the point of contact that will deliver all your html/css/js to the client. Being a SPA, everything from now on will be managed by Backbone on the client (navigation too), with the occasional call to your JSON Web Api endpoints to get and post data.

Comment: You can put the WebAPI controllers in a different library project and still host the API using the Web Application.